# How to even amplitude of the sin/chirp signal over time

Tags: python, algorithm, audio, signals, signal-processing

We have sin/chirp signal as the output of the system and its amplitude in every cycle changes over the time as wobbles over the time and like to even the uneven amplitude(peak to peak) of every cycles to max peak to peak amplitude in the whole period of the signal using python and any suggestions and approaches would be welcome, Thanks

Comment: Do you work online or offline? Offline it would be much easier. If online, how big delay can you add with this "magnitude fixer"?

Comment: Offline is also fine if that’s optimized one then we will look into online/real-time with optimization

Comment: What do you mean by optimization? time/quality?

Comment: More optimized as If that reduces the complexity/computing cycle (instructions)

Comment: I do not understand